# How do I import images using ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing

Here's my code, and I've got two problems evidently:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Component;

public class something {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/icon.png",("What a great image"));

    JPanel window = new JPanel();
    window.setLocation(100,100);
    window.setSize(300, 500);
    window.setVisible(true);

}
```

So I don't know why the JPanel won't reveal itself, and am I importing the image right? I've already created the icon and placed it in the SRC folder. If I'm not importing it right, how do I import it then? This question also applies for the Graphics Swing since I'm interested in learning that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I don't know why the JPanel won't reveal itself

You've not added it to anything that can be displayed.  A `JPanel` is just a plain container which will allow you to add other components onto it.

You need some kind of `Window` to actually display this container, for example...

```
JPanel window = new JPanel();

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(window);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Have a read through [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for more details

> I've already created the icon and placed it in the SRC folder. If I'm
>   not importing it right, how do I import it then?

That's a complicated question, because you've added the image to the `src` directory, it changes the context of how the image can be loaded.  Essentially, it becomes an embedded resource.

So instead of using...

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/icon.png",("What a great image"));
```

You would need to use something more like...

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(something.getClass().getResource("icon.png"),("What a great image"));
```

instead

You may find reading through [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) helpful

Comment: Thank you! My friends couldn't find a good way to explain to me why JPanel wouldn't work, but this seems to be the hammer that hits the nail!

Comment: Now I have a new problem in that I'm getting the following errors:


' java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
 at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
 at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
'

Comment: Try using `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(something.getClass().getResource("/icon.png"),("What a great image"));` instead

Comment: Sorry for the late reply/comment (was having dinner).

So the something.getClass().getResource doesn't work (apparently I can't make a static reference for whatever that may mean), so I removed that. The frame opens up, but the image still doesn't show. Should I use BufferedImage and Graphics instead?

Comment: Sorry, `something.class.getResource(...)` :P

Answer (score 0):

A JPanel can only be placed on a heavyweight component like a JFrame, if you look up some basic Swing tutorials you can get the basic layout of a GUI. Alternatively you can use a GUI creator like the one provided with the NetBeans IDE.
To add an image you would need to do something like

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-file"));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
add(picLabel);
```